# How to import a variable from an event

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
sugestion.on('collect', a => {
 const Suggestion = a.content;
});
console.log(`Suggestion: ${Suggestion}`);
```

I'm with TypeError with the above code.

`(node:4872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Suggestion is not defined`

Comment: Since you are getting a Promise rejection warning and are trying to leak the scope of an asynchronous variable, I think this is an AB problem and that you are going to need to read this eventually: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/691711).  Don't accidentally make the scope of `Suggestion` too broad.

Comment: Are you trying to print `a.content`? If you are, then declaring `Suggestion` outside the anonymous function scope will not work, since it will just print `undefined` (assuming `suggest.on` is async).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the Suggestion variable in scope

```
let Suggestion;
sugestion.on('collect', a => {
 Suggestion = a.content;
});
console.log(`Suggestion: ${Suggestion}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference a variable out of scope. The variable `Suggestion` only exists within the scope of the function (`a=>{}`). Either move the `console.log` line into the function, or save the value in another variable outside the scope, for future reference.

Comment: Yes I know.
I was wondering if there is how to import the variable from there, out.
_Sorry for not posting, I'm new here._

Comment: Many ways to do this. One is to the define the variable `Suggestion` above the function. But don't use `const` if you're planning to assign a value to it later. Use `let`.

Comment: Also if you are looking to log the value of `a.content`, and `suggest.on` is an async function, then you absolutely have to move the `console.log` to inside the function. Otherwise it'll just log `undefined`.